Papille et Mamille
Quelle est la signification des mots PAPILLE et MAMILLE dans les noms des restaurants " Papille " et " Chez Papille et Mamille "?

Le nom commun papille existe en français, pas le nom mamille. La présence des majuscules nous indique que les deux mots sont ici utilisés comme des noms propres. C'est d'ailleurs très fréquent de donner un nom propre à un restaurant, c'est souvent le nom du propriétaire¹. Il ne faut pas forcément trouver de sens à un nom propre.
En cherchant dans un moteur de recherche j'ai trouvé deux restaurants en France qui s'appellent Chez Papille et Mamille. En allant sur le site de la ville où un de ces restaurants est installé on peut lire que :

les nouveaux propriétaires ont souhaité rebaptiser l’établissement désormais nommé « Chez Papille et Mamille ». Un clin d’œil envers la maman [du propriétaire], décédée il y a quelques temps.

Cette dernière phrase nous indique donc que Mamille fait référence à la mère du propriétaire. Mamille n'est pas un prénom, elle ne s'appelait donc certainement pas comme ça mais le mot fait penser à Mamie qui est parfois le nom affectueux qu'on donne à sa grand-mère, il est probable que cette femme avait des petits enfants qui l'appelaient Mamie ou même Mamille. Mamille serait quand même un petit nom inhabituel pour une grand-mère. On pourrait aussi penser en extrapolant encore plus que le grand-père est (où était) surnommé Papi ou Papille.
Mais Papille fait tout de suite penser au nom commun papille, les papilles étant les petites excroissances qu'on a sur la langue et qui nous servent à percevoir le goût des aliments (on a des papilles à d'autres endroits du corps et celles sur la langue on les appelle les papilles gustatives). C'est la raison pour laquelle plusieurs restaurants en France s'appellent « Les Papilles », ou ont « papilles » dans leur nom². Mais en mettant ainsi la majuscule à Papille et en le faisant précéder de « chez », on en a fait un nom propre.  Sans demander directement au propriétaire on ne peut pas savoir si Mamille a été choisi pour rimer avec Papille, ou si la grand-mère était surnommée mamille au départ.

¹On trouvera certainement beaucoup de restaurants ou bistrots appelés Chez Paul, Chez Louise, Chez Alain, Chez Françoise, etc...
²Cocottes et papilles, Les papilles de Pierre, Aux papilles de...

Merci beaucoup, None,  pour une réponse si profonde !

Dans le même registre, on peut entendre aussi papouille et mamouille.

@jlliagre Dans la restauration ? Ou plutôt dans le secteur de la petite enfance ? En tous cas ça fait guili-guili !

@None Pas de papouilles gustatives, ce seraient peut-être des papayes et des mamayes,  donc oui, les petits-enfants qui parlent à/de leur parents ou grands-parents :-)
